# Nav bar not collapsing after htaccess configuration

Tags: .htaccess, navbar, toggle

Respectable Gurus,
I am new to .htaccess, I write it for my site and also obtained desired result but the only issue I observed with navbar toggle, It does not work on prefix with download/url and page/url, but it work with base url and without prefix in urls.
My htaccess file configuration is as bellow

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(comments.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)/?$  single.php?bookid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)/?$  comments.php?bookid=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ autherbooks.php?authid=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
# navbar toggle works Only with bellow url
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ autherbooks.php?authid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Any help / suggestion will be highly appreciated